# Salary calculator (over time pay) require assistance of senior level programmers

Tags: c++

4.16 (Salary Calculator) Develop a C++ program that uses a while statement to determine the
gross pay for each of several employees.
When someone works 41 hours or more. They get paid 1.5x more so my problem is that in my else if statement. I did rate * 1.5 which should translate into 10 * 1.5 = 15 but I get 425 because my code on the top probably, but I don't understand it at the moment.
He gave us this example. Which I'm trying to emulate.

"
Enter hours worked (-1 to end): 41

Enter hourly rate of the employee ($00.00): 10.00

Salary is $415.00
"

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{ 
double salary=0,rate=0,hours=0,counter=0;
cout << "Enter your hours worked: ";
cin >> hours;
cout << "Enter your rate: ";
cin >> rate;

while(counter<=hours)
{   salary=hours*rate;
    counter++;
}
    if(hours==-1)
        {exit(0);
    }
    else if(hours>=41)
    {
    rate = rate * 1.5;
    salary = salary + rate;
    }

cout << "$" << salary;

return 0;
```

}

Comment: You're calculating 41 * 10 + 15. You want to be calculating 40 * 10 + 1 * 15.

Comment: Work out with a pencil and  paper how you would do this calculation. (Hint: If you get paid 40 hours at regular rate, but work 41, you get overtime for 1 extra hour, so the overtime would be (HoursWorked - RegularPayHours) * OvertimeRate, right?)

Comment: That loop is completely redundant.

Comment: I need to use a loopty loop or else death will be my punishment

Comment: You need to better define your question, or lack of assistance will be your punishment. If you think you're required to write gratuitously bad code, you misunderstood the requirement.

Comment: Are you sure you are required to use a loop? There's absolutely no instructional value to complicating the implementation with one. It's a simple equation you need.

Comment: 4.16 (Salary Calculator) Develop a C++ program that uses a while statement to determine the
gross pay for each of several employees.

Comment: Problem is from [*C++ How to Program, 8th ed.*](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/cplusplus/9780132777650/control-statements-part-1/ch04lev1sec17).

Comment: @HotshotGG _'**each of several employees**'_ not `hours`!!

Answer (score 0):

The loop you used has no functionality related to the problem, so I omitted it. Below is what will work. As others have said, define why you need a loop. I'm guessing you need to loop the code so the user can repeat this to their heart's content. If that is the case, I'll let you try to figure out how to break out of the loop when a user enters -1.

```
if (hours == -1)
    exit(0);

else if (hours <= 40) 
    salary = rate * hours;

else {
    double overtimeHours = hours - 40;
    salary = rate * 40;
    rate = rate * 1.5;
    salary = salary + (rate * overtimeHours);
}

cout << "$" << salary;
```

Comment: 4.16 (Salary Calculator) Develop a C++ program that uses a while statement to determine the
gross pay for each of several employees. that's just the first sentence of the assignment. I've probably should've included it but didn't.

Comment: Okay, so several employees. Try moving your cins into a while loop. Then check to see if the user inputted -1, if so, exit the loop. If not, compute the salary.

Comment: in the example cpp. file he gave everyone. He made another cout<<"ask for hours"; at the end so if I figure this out. I just copy and paste.

Comment: Attempt to use the code I gave in my answer and incorporate it into a while loop. Then edit your question with your new attempt and where you are stuck.

Comment: It worked but I didn't put it in the while loop since it ended with the { } after counter++;. I was thinking about overtime= (hours - 40) * rate * 1.5; before considering this but it didn't work. I would up vote you but I always get down voted so u can get a blow kiss <3.